# Sum of sale of each partnumber and partnumber have its substitute partnumber in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have two table first have part number and sale of each month.
And another table have substitute part of part number.

**Table 1**

```
Partnumber     jun19sale   jul19sale
A                 1                1
B                 2                1
C                 3                4
E                 5                3
D                 1                2
```

**Table2**

```
Partnumber     subpart   
A                 B               
A                 C               
A                 D
```

How can i get something like this.

```
Partnumber     jun19sale   jul19sale
A                  7               8
B                  7               8
C                  7               8
E                  5               3
D                  7               8
```

I tried with subqueries with or,in which give me accurate result, but it takes too much time. Because tables have large amount of data.

Comment: Are you able to get the result you want? What did you try? If you want to adress a perforamnce issue, try indexes.

Comment: You should include your table structure, indexes, amount of data and your current SQL. Otherwise people are just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Long way

Join the sales numbers to the parts (associate each sale with a sub part) using a left join (some records in sales will not associate), group and sum on the parts partnumber if it exists, or the sales part number if it doesn't (the sales are expressed on subparts and main parts so we want to map some subparts in sales to a main part). Once we have our sales expressed as main parts only, left join (otherwise you won't get row E in the output) it to a list of parts where main part is mapped to both main part and sub part (otherwise you won't get row A in the output)

```
    SELECT 
      COALESCE(parts.partnumber, sales.partnumber) partnumber,
      sum(jun19sale) as jun19sum,
      sum(jul19sale) as jul19sum
    FROM
      table1 sales
      LEFT JOIN
      table2 parts 
      ON
        sales.partnumber = parts.subpart
    GROUP BY COALESCE(parts.partnumber, sales.partnumber)
```

This will give totals like `A, 7, 8` etc. Now we need to join that back to a mapping of the parts to subparts that also includes the main part mapped to the main part (as a subpart), like this:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(msparts.subpart, subsum.partnumber) as partnumber,
  subsum.jun19sum,
  subsum.jul19sum
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT partnumber, partnumber as subpart FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT partnumber, subpart FROM table1
  ) msparts
  RIGHT JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
      COALESCE(parts.partnumber, sales.partnumber) partnumber,
      sum(jun19sale) as jun19sum,
      sum(jul19sale) as jul19sum
    FROM
      table1 sales
      LEFT JOIN
      table2 parts 
      ON
        sales.partnumber = parts.subpart
    GROUP BY COALESCE(parts.partnumber, sales.partnumber)
  ) subsum
  ON
    msparts.partnumber = subsum.partnumber
```

We need a trick though, to prevent the A row from getting lost, because the parts table maps a to b,c,d but not to a- this means if we join the sims and show the subpart, row A will disappear from the results. If we add a inch of fake rows that maps A to A as well as to B C and D, then the row will remain. This is what the UNION ALL bit does

### Short way

this might be simpler to achieve using analytic/window functions to do the same thing;

```
SELECT
  sales.partnumber,
  SUM(jun19sale) OVER(PARTITION BY COALESCE(parts.partnumber, sales.partnumber)) jun19sale,
  SUM(jul19sale) OVER(PARTITION BY COALESCE(parts.partnumber, sales.partnumber)) jul19sale
FROM
  table1 sales
  LEFT JOIN
  table2 parts
  ON sales.partnumber = parts.subpart
```

Here we use the sales table as a driver so we keep rows A and E by default. We still do a left join on the parts table so some parts like B C D are mapped to A. We ask the analytic to sum on the group of main part from parts or if it is null, main part from sales (this is the PARTITION BY)

COALESCE is a cross platform compatible version of IFNULL